# Can the gcc preprocessor know if a plugin has been loaded

Tags: gcc

Assume I have a plugin and I load it using the gcc -fplugin=foo.so...

Is there any preprocessor symbol or macro that gets defined that I can use to conditionally compile out language features that plugin requires.

Of course I can provide that macro on the command line, e.g -Dplugin_foo_loaded.

But it would be better if such macros were generated by the act of loading the plugin.

What is the answer?

Comment: Why do you ask, and why do you care? What is your plugin trying to do?

Comment: Currently I am just learning how to wield the mighty sword of gcc plugins. I don't want to do anything in particular (yet). I used to hack gcc directly back when that was practical. Once that ceased to be practical I gave up. I only just recently discovered the feature so I'm learning it. And I'm aware of the awesome MELT. I'm a lisp person myself. But as I say, just learning for now

Comment: I certainly will at some point, but the learning curve for gcc internals is about as steep as they come, and stacking MELT on top will fry my brain. MELT will be waiting for me once I can understand what it does.

Comment: On http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html you'l find several tutorials about GCC plugins ....

Comment: Thanks a lot. [this](http://www.grsecurity.net/~ephox/const_plugin/constify_plugin.c) was the best example I have seen yet.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (GCC 4.9) you cannot do that, since there is no plugin hooks related to the preprocessor.

I guess that the simplest way would be to pass a `-DMYPLUGIN`. Or define some builtin in your plugin.

PS. If you are looking for some tutorial material about GCC plugins consider also [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) and some [documentation](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) there (e.g. slides on [GCC plugins thru the MELT example](http://gcc-melt.org/gcc-plugin-MELT-LinuxCollabSummit2014.pdf); Linux Foundation, march 2014)

Comment: OK, it's a shame the preprocessor has no plugin capability. I'm not sure if it could use the same architecture as the existing plugin system, but I could imagine it would be useful, especially for code which relies on the preprocessor too much.

Comment: It is just the point of getting some plugin hooks added into the trunk. However, some influential GCC folks are not convinced about adding them; you need to show them some existing GCC plugins which could benefit of such hooks.